# No public RealmResults<E> Constructor?

Tags: java, android, realm

I've got a table that has `Realm Objects` I'm calling `Foo`.
One of the columns of `Foo` points to another `Realm Object`, `Bar`.
I want to query table `Foo` and pick out all of the `Bar` objects I need, and then add them to a `RealmBaseAdapter`.

However, to my knowledge, `RealmBaseAdapter` only takes a `RealmResults` list in it's constructor. 
How would I form a `RealmResults` of `Bar` without querying the `Bar` table? 
Or, how would I query the `Foo` table and get back a `RealmResults` of `Bar`?

For example, say you had a table of product's and product segments, e.g. rice krispies, corn flakes, fruit loops would all belong to the cereal product segment. I wish to query a table of products by some specification, and list all of the product segments that are contained in the result.

Comment: So `Foo` has-a `Bar` and both `Foo` and `Bar` extend from `RealmObject`?

Comment: @bot Indeed. To be more explicit, Foo has one Bar. But Bar has no knowledge of which Foo's have it as their Bar.

Comment: @bot , I don't want all of the Bar Objects, just the ones that correspond to the Foo Objects returned by a specific query. For example, Say you had a table of product's and product segments, e.g. rice krispies, corn flakes, fruit loops would all belong to the cereal product segment. 
I wish to query a table of products by some specification, and list all of the product segments that are contained in the result.

Comment: How about using the [allObjects](https://realm.io/docs/java/api/io/realm/Realm.html#allObjects-java.lang.Class-) method from the `Realm` class? It seems to be returning all the `RealmObject` instances of a particular type wrapped into a `RealmResults` object which can then be passed to `RealmBaseAdapter`. If this works for you, I shall post it as an answer. Don't have the infrastructure to try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the order of the comments, I edited the link so your comment went up before mine. Anyway, can't you call the `allObjects` method with the `Foo` class? I believe the code to fetch the `Bar` corresponding to each `Foo` is already present in `Foo`?. Anyway, I guess I am not the right person to answer this question unless I get my hands on a computer.

Comment: Go ahead and post. It sounds like you have a good way to solve this.

Comment: Not really. This is not my area of expertise. Btw, if you query a `Foo` in your existing code, do you automatically get a value for the `Bar` or is `Bar` null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76197/discussion-between-michael-alan-huff-and-bot).

Comment: Considering you seem to have solved the problem by creating a new adapter, can you show by answering your question what the solution is? For the sake of SO :)

Comment: @epicpandaforce, will do so first thing tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there was no way to do this directly, I ended up making my own adapter.

```
 public class BarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bar>  {

      //code to instantiate the adapter, inflate views, etc

 }
```

This part was trivial, the only hard work to be done was by curating a query from Foo-->Bar that would get me the results that I wanted. It ended up looking something like this,

```
    // where fooType was what I wanted to ween out the Foo results on before
    // selecting Bar objects.
    RealmQuery<Foo> fooRealmQuery = realm
            .where(Foo.class)
            .equalTo("fooType", "desired type")
            .or()
            .equalTo("fooType", "other type");
    RealmResults<Foo> fooList = fooRealmQuery.findAll();

    List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
    for (Foo foo : fooList) {

        Bar bar = foo.getBar();

        if (!barList.contains(bar)) {
            barList.add(bar);
            Log.d(TAG, "added " + bar.getName());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "I already had that bar");
        }
    }

    adapter = new BarAdapter(this, barList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now things work well. Also, Realm is fast enough that I can query right as I'm creating the adapter and I see no performance lag :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is currently not possible using the current `RealmBaseAdapter`, at least not if you want to display Bar objects from a Foo query.

If you don't want to maintain a relationship from Bar to Foo, I would recommend creating your `RealmAdapter` instead where able to filter your Foo query for the Bar objects you wanted to display. The `RealmBaseAdapter` contains very little code, so it should be fairly easy to customize: [RealmBaseAdapter.java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java)

Comment: Thanks Christian! I ended up going with another solution. However, if you were to post some sample code with what you're talking about I'd gladly accept your answer.